# How can I upgrade my device firmware with BlueNRG?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, ota, dfu

I'm currently working on a BLE device. This device has no screen nor keyboard. It is using a STM32L0 and is connected to an application on android.

I want to make a DFU (device firmware update) via bluetooth so I can change the version of my product in a simple way. I would like to have my application giving via BLE packets of the new version of the firmware.

How can I process to do this ?

What do I have to do from each side of the game ? (android and my product)

I wanted to upgrade the firmware first (in order to try) into a Nucleo IDB05A1 with the L073RZ and an app (NRF connect)  but still no results

I've looked in a lot of different website but with no effective results ... 
[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T80kzxu7M04) is what i want but it's not at all in connection with my products ...

Comment: There is some good info to be found here:
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/09/45/83/e0/7d/67/46/2c/DM00115333.pdf/files/DM00115333.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00115333.pdf

Shows how ST Micro are doing OTA flash to their BlueNRG devices.

Comment: I already read this file but the thing is that i woud not like to use EWARM workspace, and this is explaining it with it. Any other Idea ? :)

Comment: Do you have any other idea ? I'm also looking for a tutorial but nothing appear :(